# pymc implementation of ThinkBayes 1.3 cookie problem

Tags: python, markov-chain-montecarlo, pymc

This is obviously overkill for [this problem](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkbayes/html/thinkbayes002.html#toc9), but I thought it would help cement the concepts for me.

The problem:

> Suppose there are two bowls of cookies. Bowl 1 contains 30 vanilla cookies and 10 chocolate cookies. Bowl 2 contains 20 of each.
>   Now suppose you choose one of the bowls at random and, without looking, select a cookie at random. The cookie is vanilla. What is the probability that it came from Bowl 1?

Here is my attempt:

```
import pymc as mc

which_bowl = mc.Categorical('which_bowl', [.5,.5])

bowl_probs = [ 
   # vanilla, chocolate
   [.75,      .25],       # bowl 1
   [.5,       .5 ],       # bowl 2
]

@mc.deterministic
def bowl(which_bowl=which_bowl):
   return bowl_probs[which_bowl]

observation = mc.Categorical('obs', bowl, value=0, observed=True)

model = mc.Model([which_bowl, bowl, observation])
mcmc = mc.MCMC(model)
mcmc.sample(15000, 3000)

bowl_data = mcmc.trace('bowl')[:]

print 1.0 * sum(bowl_data) / len(bowl_data)
```

Solving this by hand gives:

```
.6
```

But the code above results in

```
[ 0.64997917  0.35002083]
```

That .6499 doesn't seem close enough to the expected .6. I'd appreciate help identifying what's wrong with my setup.

Comment: Interesting.   I'm running this same code at home on a different computer and I consistently get .60-ish.   I'll try again on Monday on my other computer and see if it still consistently gives a high number.  Curious what values others get when running the above code.

Comment: If anyone is still interested I see my problem now.
    
    "bowl_data = mcmc.trace('bowl')[:]"

should have been

   "bowl_data = mcmc.trace('which_bowl')[:]"

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at implementing OPs model in PyMC3:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
import theano

with pm.Model() as model:
    p = theano.shared( np.array([
        # vanilla, chocolate
        [.75, .25],  # bowl 1
        [.5, .5],    # bowl 2
    ]) )
    which_bowl = pm.Categorical('which_bowl', np.array([.5, .5]))
    bowl = pm.Deterministic('bowl', p[which_bowl])
    observation = pm.Categorical('obs', bowl, observed=0)
    step = pm.Metropolis()
    trace = pm.sample(150000, init=None, tune=10000)

bowl_trace = trace['which_bowl']

for i in range(2):
    print('Prob the cookie was picked from bowl #{}: {:.5f}'.format(i, (bowl_trace == i).mean()))
```

which yields

```
Prob the cookie was picked from bowl #0: 0.59896
Prob the cookie was picked from bowl #1: 0.40104
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your efforts on this.

FWIW, I got it to work with some minor tweaks

```
import pymc as mc

bowl = mc.Categorical('which_bowl', [.5,.5])

p = [
   # vanilla, chocolate
   [.75,      .25],       # bowl 1
   [.5,       .5 ],       # bowl 2
]

@mc.deterministic
def bowl_selection(p=p, bowl=bowl):
   return p[bowl]

observation = mc.Categorical('obs', bowl_selection, value=0, observed=True)

mcmc = mc.MCMC([bowl, p, bowl_selection, observation])
mcmc.sample(15000, 3000)

bowl_trace = mcmc.trace('which_bowl')[:]
```

Now the posterior probabilities for the hypotheses are

```
(bowl_trace == 0).sum()*1./ bowl_trace.shape[0]
```

and

```
(bowl_trace == 1).sum()*1./ bowl_trace.shape[0]
```

Comment: Struggling to implement this in PyMC3... It is unclear to me how to create deterministic variable for "p" and then how to index it. Finally, not clear how to show what variable is observed.